# Periodic expansion of function

Tags: graphing-functions, periodic-functions

Let $ \tilde{f}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be the 2-periodic expansion of the function $ f: [-1,1[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ given by $ f(x)=x $.

But how can I make a graph of $ \tilde{f} $ and how can I detemine $ \tilde{f}(3) $ and $ \tilde{f}(5)?$

I know I should use the formula $ \tilde{g}(x+np)=g(x) $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [plot it with WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20mod%28x,2,-1%29,%20x=-4..4):

```
plot mod(x,2,-1), x=-4..4
```

[image]

In general `mod(x, n)`, gives the remainder when $x$ is divided by $n$.  When $n=2$, we'd expect something between $0$ and $2$.  In the three argument form, `mod(x,n,m)`, $m$ is an offset.  Thus we get something between $m$ and $m+n$.  In this case, something between $-1$ and $1$.